# printf SSE variables __m128i in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, simd

I have some code that uses SIMD optimization and various __m128i variables. Obviously, printf can't handle them. Is there an easy way for me to print their contents?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with C/C++.

Comment: Get bottom and upper parts as int64_t and print those? Roll your own to string conversion by dividing by ten until you reach 0, converting to ASCII, and then reversing the string?

Comment: That's definitively an option I considered as well. I was hoping for an even easier solution (although this isn't hard at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this function to print them:

```
void print128_num(__m128i var)
{
    uint16_t *val = (uint16_t*) &var;//can also use uint32_t instead of 16_t
    printf("Numerical: %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n", 
           val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], 
           val[6], val[7]);
}
```

You split 128bits into 16-bits(or 32-bits) before printing them.

This is a way of 64-bit splitting and printing if you have 64-bit support available:

```
void print128_num(__m128i var) 
{
    int64_t *v64val = (int64_t*) &var;
    printf("%.16llx %.16llx\n", v64val[1], v64val[0]);
}
```

Replace `llx` with `lld` if u want `int` output.

Comment: `printf("Numerical: %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n", 
           val[7], val[6], val[5], val[4], val[3], val[2], 
           val[1], val[0]);` seems more logical printing order.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer based on Vlad's approach:

```
__m128i var;
 printf("0x%I64x%I64x\n",var.m128i_i64[1], var.m128i_i64[0]);
```

This prints the whole 128 bit value as a hex string.